# Odds ratio and confidence intervals from glmer output

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have made a model that looks at a number of variables and the effect that has on pregnancy outcome. The outcome is a grouped binary. A mob of animals will have 34 pregnant and 3 empty, the next will have 20 pregnant and 4 empty and so on.

I have modelled this data using the `glmer` function where y is the pregnancy outcome (pregnant or empty).

```
mclus5 <- glmer(y~adg + breed + bw_start + year + (1|farm),
                data=dat, family=binomial)
```

I get all the usual output with coefficients etc. but for interpretation I would like to transform this into odds ratios and confidence intervals for each of the coefficients.

In past logistic regression models I have used the following code

```
round(exp(cbind(OR=coef(mclus5),confint(mclus5))),3)
```

This would very nicely provide what I want, but it does not seem to work with the model I have run.

Does anyone know a way that I can get this output for my model through R?

Comment: Type this: `?fixef` and `class(mclus5)` and `showMethods("fixef", includeDefs=TRUE)`. `glmer` is an S4 function.

Answer (score 23):

The only real difference is that you have to use `fixef()` rather than `coef()` to extract the fixed-effect coefficients (`coef()` gives you the estimated coefficients *for each group*).

I'll illustrate with a built-in example from the `lme4` package.

```
library("lme4")
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
               data = cbpp, family = binomial)
```

Fixed-effect coefficients and confidence intervals, log-odds scale:

```
cc <- confint(gm1,parm="beta_")  ## slow (~ 11 seconds)
ctab <- cbind(est=fixef(gm1),cc)
```

(If you want faster-but-less-accurate Wald confidence intervals you can use `confint(gm1,parm="beta_",method="Wald")` instead; this will be equivalent to @Gorka's answer but marginally more convenient.)

Exponentiate to get odds ratios:

```
rtab <- exp(ctab)
print(rtab,digits=3)
##               est 2.5 % 97.5 %
## (Intercept) 0.247 0.149  0.388
## period2     0.371 0.199  0.665
## period3     0.324 0.165  0.600
## period4     0.206 0.082  0.449
```

A marginally simpler/more general solution:

```
library(broom.mixed)
tidy(gm1,conf.int=TRUE,exponentiate=TRUE,effects="fixed")
```

for Wald intervals, or add `conf.method="profile"` for profile confidence intervals.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there is another, much faster way (if you are OK with a less accurate result).

From: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/melogit.htm

First we get the confidence intervals for the Estimates

```
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(mclus5)))
# table of estimates with 95% CI
tab <- cbind(Est = fixef(mclus5), LL = fixef(mclus5) - 1.96 * se, UL = fixef(mclus5) + 1.96 * se)
```

Then the odds ratios with 95% CI

```
print(exp(tab), digits=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Other option I believe is to just use package `emmeans` :

```
library(emmeans)
data.frame(confint(pairs(emmeans(fit, ~ factor_name,type="response"))))
```

Comment: No need to wrap the call in `data.frame`, though. In fact, doing so suppresses messages that may be useful.

Comment: Ha yes that's a good point - I usually make a data frame out of it to save it to a csv file though. But probably best to do that in two steps then...

Comment: note that this probably wants to switch to using `emmeans` now.

Comment: Yes of course one can also use the newer packae emmeans now, good point!

Comment: @BenBolker, the results from `emmeans` are different from  the ones you provided in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417108/1060349), including the ones given by `broom.mixed`.

Comment: This answer is providing confidence intervals on pairwise contrasts. `emmeans()` is designed for providing estimates and CIs for expected marginal means, contrasts, etc. - different from the parameters themselves.  If you want an explanation of the differences (which might be better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), please post a new question with a reproducible example and a clearly articulated question ...